# Express-Handlebars block helper doesn't process local data

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to make a dynamic input selector using Handlebars block helper.
The code below works when run on a Handlebars tutorial site [http://www.javascriptoo.com/handlebars-js], or when inserted into a normal html web page.

```
<td>
<div id="placeHolder">testing</div>
    <script id="siteOptions" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <select>
       {{#each options}}
           {{this.key}}
           <option {{this.hidden}}>{{this.optName}}</option>
       {{/each}}
        </select>
    </script>
</td>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs /jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.rc.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var source = document.getElementById("siteOptions").innerHTML;
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var myData = {
        options: [
            { "hidden":"hidden","name": "Company" },
            { "hidden":"","optName": "Plant" },
            { "hidden":"","optName": "Area" },
            { "hidden":"","optName": "Machine" }
        ]
    };
    console.log("myData: "+myData.options[2].optName);
    console.log("myObj: "+ template(myData.options));
    document.getElementById("placeHolder").innerHTML = template(myData);
```

In both Firefox and Chrome I end up with an empty

The two console.log() below shows:

```
console.log("myData: "+myData.options[2].optName);// Area ,Proves data is there
console.log("myObj: "+ template(myData.options));//<select>[empty]</select>
```

What could possibly be stopping it from working in FF and Chrome?

Comment: Alas: I blew my first entry.  Some typing did not show up.

Comment: Blew it again. I hit return.  I need to add- "But in both Firefox and Chrome I end up with an empty <select></select>.  The select element is there but there is nothing in it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  [Try this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help with formatting your question.

Comment: I tried this in a jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/1ef6qmea/.  I did have to remove an extra space in your jquery script tag.  But if that's not the problem, you may have other code that is causing the issue

Comment: Barbara, thank you for your attention.  After another day of hacking, I have learned that the problem has something to do with the data I am asking the template() method to process.